# CouchDB on Local Network

Tags: couchdb, localhost

I have couch running and set up a local, static ip on my computer so that I could have a local network going, 127.0.0.1:5984/_utils works, but my static ip 192.168.1.4:5984/_utils doesnt. I've tried pinging 192.168.1.4, and that goes though but 192.168.1.4:5984 doesnt.
Thoughts?

EDIT: I am working in a windows environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at `etc/couchdb/local.ini` file read by couch. There is a `bind_address` option in `[httpd]` section. If you set it to `0.0.0.0` CouchDB will listen on all the interfaces.

Comment: Okay So I tried that, and tried using 192.168.1.4, still got the same problems, though I believe I needed to do this anyway, any other thoughts?

Comment: Try `netstat -a -t -n` in the command line and see which address CouchDB is bound to (look for port 5984). If it's 0.0.0.0 or 192.168.1.4, then it's the problem with other components, e.g. a firewall.

Comment: firewall. that was the issue. Can't believe I missed that. thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to restart the system.. I was stuck and every setting was correct but until I restarted the system, everything goes fine by now

Comment: You can also modify the `bind_address` through `127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/config.html`

Comment: don't forget to uncomment the port and bind_address lines and restart database